# Writing Mocha Test for Async functions which uses setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, gulp-mocha

Somehow I'm not able to write Mocha JS test for a relatively very simple function. The JavaScript Source file looks like this

```
exports.cb = function() {
    console.log("The function is called after 3 seconds");
}

exports.testfn = function(cb) {
  setTimeout(cb, 3000);
}
```

And the test code is written as

```
describe('Main Test', function(){
  it('A callback Tests', function(done){
    asn.testfn(asn.cb);
    done();
  });
});
```

I'm encountering 2 problems.

- 1. The test code ends immediately with done()
- 2. If I don't call done(), then the function is called but tests fails because it expected to call done() for async functions

I've looked into documentations but not sure how this can be done.

I can write tests using promises and it works fine. But for the scenarios where we need to use setTimeout, how shall it be done?

Comment: What are you trying to test? `testfn` or `cb`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming what you're trying to test is `testfn`, you wouldn't use `cb`, you'd use a callback in the test; see comments:

```
describe('Main Test', function(){
  it('testfn calls the function after three seconds', function(done){
    // Remember the start time
    var start = Date.now();
    // Schedule callback
    asn.testfn(function() {
        // Has it been at least three seconds?
        if (Date.now() - start < 3000) {
            // No, trigger an error
        } else {
            // Yes, all's good!
            done();
        }
    });
  });
});
```

If you want to call `asn.cb` for some reason, you'd do it in the anonymous function above, but if you want to test `asn.cb`, you should do that serparately from testing `asn.testfn`.

Answer (score 0):

```
describe('Main Test', function(){
  it('A callback Tests', function(done){
    asn.testfn(function() {
        asn.cb();
        done();
    });
  });
});
```